# Merging of Data of two database having same tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, opencart

I am kind of new to OpenCart having two projects with the same name.

> Old Project and New Project

I have two database 
1.Database1(old)
2.Database2.(new)
both have different data but have the same Table.
What I want is :

> I Just want to simply merge all the data from old to new without affecting the data in the table in both the database.(Complete merge of Database).
>   i.e Old data will come first and New Data will go after it.

Can anyone please tell me the safest way to do it.
Help will be Appreciated. 
Thanks

> Note: In both database, i have around 100 tables.

Comment: That might not work, if you have some columns which are marked as unique

Comment: Can you say the way to solve it, i have aroyund 50 tables in my both db

Comment: ok, can you please say me merging of two tables in one table??

Comment: You would have to use an export and import, I think. They do exist for OpenCart. First you export from one database, probably do a bit of processing of the data, and then import it in other database. Make sure this process doesn't overwrite any existing data, and reports any data collisions. *MAKE A BACKUP FIRST*

Comment: This is a very unclear question, you mention "data" but you're not really explaining exactly what you want to merge - do you want to merge products, categories, customers, orders? What about banners, layouts, design and extensions? My advice is give up with the idea you think you can merge the databases and write a script to move the data from one to the other.

Comment: see..i have two databases having different name but having same table name.So i want to merge one table from one db to another table in another db without replacing old data. Please write the script to move the data from one to another

Comment: May be this module will help you,  https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=25450

Comment: link is not working.... can you provide another one